# jQuery Syntax Check

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

If I were to convert this Prototype snippet to jQuery, would this be correct?

**Prototype:**

```
this.selected.observe('click', this.toggle.bindAsEventListener(this))
```

**jQuery**

```
$j(this).bind('click').toggle(this);
```

How far off am I?

Comment: You have a way of restoring it, right? Otherwise it'll just disappear and be unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).bind('click', function(){ $(this).toggle(); });
```

The only confusion I have is what is the this in the beginning?  Usually you would do something more along the lines of $('.toggleable').bind... using some form of selector.

you could also use:

```
$('.toggleable').live('click', ...
```

instead.  This gives the added bonus of being callable outside of the $(document).ready() function, as when new toggleable objects are added their click event will be set, rather than bind which binds to all current available toggleable objects, which if not called on document.ready could be none.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j(this).click(function(){
    $j(this).toggle();
});
```

Note: `.click(handler)` is a shortcut for `.bind('click', handler)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
$(this).bind('click',function () {
    $(this)
}
```

Remember that 'this' refers to something else when you use it inside the function. It will now be the thing you're calling it on. Ex)

```
$('#object').bind('click', function() {
    $(this) //'this' refers to the 'object'
}
```